# Reference to a field before function definition

Tags: c++, function

I am going through a c++ code base and in the header file (Executor.h) there is the public field definition

```
typedef std::pair<ExecutionState*,ExecutionState*> StatePair;
```

Inside the cpp file (Executor.cpp) there is a line

```
Executor::StatePair 
Executor::fork(ExecutionState &current, ref<Expr> condition, bool isInternal) { /* function definition */ }
```

in which this field is referenced right before one of the member function definitions

What is the purpose of stating the field name right before the definition ? Is it scoping issues ?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is the function's return type :^)

Comment: Yeah it is and I believe that this was a stupid question.. got confused for a second I guess :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StatePair` is a *type*.  Its purpose in front of the function definition is to state the return type of the function

Note the `typedef` in the definition of `StatePair`.  It introduces a name alias for a type.  In this case `std::pair<ExecutionState*,ExecutionState*>` will also be called `StatePair`, so you don't have to write that long type name

The return type of a function names the type that the value returned from the function must belong to.  E.g. in the case of

```
int f();
```

the function `f` must return an integer (`int`), so we could write a definition like this:

```
int f() {return 0;}
```

there could be other statements in the function body, but the last one has to be a `return` with an integer value after it (in the bavode example the value is `0`)

As C++ does not care about new lines (treats them as regular white-space), the format

```
int
f() {...}
```

is the same as for the above function.

Comment: Ahh ok I am used to see the return type on the left so I guess I was a bit confused for a second :)

Comment: In C++, whitespace doesn't matter.

Comment: @JohnDibling - except where it does